# How are you supposed to create a command line tool that uses swift argument parser?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools, swift-argumentparser

I've tried two different approaches, each of which fails in a different way:

### Approach #1:

- Create folder for the project.

In terminal:

- cd to folder
- swift package init --type executable
- xed Package.swift

The xed command opens the Package.swift file as if it was an Xcode project.

I then attempt to use Xcode's File>add package dependencies to add swift-agrument-parser to the project.

**Problem:** The "Copy dependency" button doesn't do anything.

### Approach #2:

- In Xcode, select File>new project, Mac OS Command line tool.
- Select File>add package dependencies.

**Problem:**

It can't find the ArugmentParser
Library not loaded: @rpath/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser

I've tried replacing main.swift with a file called .swift that contains an `@main` directory and a ParsableCommand struct. I've tried cleaning the build folder.

---

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to create the package with approach #1, swift package init, then edit the package.swift file and add the swift-argument-parser dependencies manually. I don't work much with SPM, so I have to fumble around for a long while to figure out the correct syntax and get it to work. This usually leads to several false starts and errors, and a lot of frustration.

Shouldn't there be a simple, "do A, B, and C" set of steps that makes this work without having to clean up a bunch of errors or manually compose an SPM Package.swift file?

Shouldn't the IDE let me create a command line tool, add the swift-argument-parser package, and build my tool the first time without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution of Approach #1:**

Open the package in Xcode, go to Package.swift and add the dependencies like in this example which is called `MyExecutable`

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyExecutable",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser", from: "1.3.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .executableTarget(
            name: "MyExecutable", dependencies: [
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser"),
            ]),
    ]
)
```

**Solution of Approach #2:**

The default implementation of Swift Argument Parser adds an executable `generate-manual`.
Delete it in the target > General

Comment: That does seem to fix the problem for approach #2. (You can also select "target none" for the generate-manual package product in the dialog that comes up when you add swift-argument-manager as a dependency to the project.) What is "generate-manual", and why does including it in the target break the build?

Comment: And do you know how to add the argument parser dependency to approach #1?

Comment: Actually, I am able to add the argument parser to the project MANUALLY in approach 1, by carefully editing the changes into the Package.swift file. Both approaches don't work "out of the box", which is maddening.

Comment: As mentioned, I have figured out how to **manually** add the swift-argument-parser package to a project created with approach 1, but that requires figuring out the syntax of the Package.swift file and correctly adding the dependency in 2 different places. I always mess up the nesting of the parentheses and braces in the second one. My point is that there is no approach that lets you add this package to your project without having to make fussy, hard-to-remember changes to the project in order to get it to work. I was hoping there was a to add the package (or any package) without manual changes

Comment: I understand, there is no other way, but with a bit knowledge of Swift it's not that hard to add the dependencies, and SPM is pretty well documented.